# Search mails with french accent in gmail with python imaplib

Tags: python, character-encoding, gmail, imaplib

Imaplib search function throws an exception

> "SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']"

as soon as I use a character with a french accent, like é, è or à.

Here is my code:

```
import imaplib

imap_conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
imap_conn.login(login, password)
imap_conn.select()
typ, mail_ids = imap_conn.search(
    "utf-8",
    '(SUBJECT "bonne année")'.encode('utf-8'))
```

If I search "bonne annee", I have no exception and the search function returns IDs.

Do you know what I should modify?

I saw examples setting imap_conn.literal, and then calling imap_conn.search("utf-8", "SUBJECT").
I agree to use this solution, but what I search look like (FROM "myaddress@gmail.com" SUBJECT "bonne annee" SINCE "01-Dec-2021") and I did not found how to use literal with several criteria.
If somebody has the solution, I am interested!

Thank!

Comment: remove "utf-8" arg from serach methode

Comment: @eshirvana Did you try? I get "'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9'"

Comment: The first duplicate _asks_ about ISO-8859-1, but the answer includes working code for UTF-8.

Comment: thanks for the replies, guys! I added a clarification at the end of my question since I did not manage to use the literal solution.